# Unable to implement Security Rules in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to access data only for the nodes where `severity` value is 3,For that i implemented security rules to only read desired nodes. But the problem is that it retrieve all the data including the one which have severity <3 or >3.

The number i mentioned against the node is its `severity` values, i.e 6 and 2

[image: DB]

Here is Security Rules
[image: Security Rules]

I am following [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#structuring_your_rules) to set up the rules.
How can i set this?

Answer (score 0):

Security rules [cascade](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization), so if you grant read access at the root (which you are doing with the rule `".read": auth != null`, it will ignore the stricter rules that are deeper in your DB structure. Put `".read": false` at the root of your DB instead, and you should see this work.